# Laravel inserting new record

Tags: database, laravel, model, insert

I have a problem with inserting new record to data

There is a part of videocontroller:

```
  $galleryName = Input::get('name');
  $galleryID = Foto::create($galleryName);
```

here model:

```
class Foto extends Eloquent {

    public static function create($name)
    {
        return DB::table('galleries')->insert_get_id(array('name' => $name));
    }
}
```

Declaration of `Foto::create()` should be compatible with

```
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::create(array $attributes)
```

What I should fix?

Comment: Like @JosephSilber, or use `Input::only('name')` which returns single element array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eloquent's `create` method takes an array. You cannot change that.

If you need this functionality, create a different method:

```php
public static function createFromName($name)
{
    return DB::table('galleries')->insertGetId(compact('name'));
}
```

Then use that in your controller:

```php
$galleryName = Input::get('name');

$galleryID = Foto::createFromName($galleryName);
```

Comment: when I want to add array to database: $tab = array('name' => `Input::get('name'), 'user_id' => Auth::id());

  Foto::create($tab);` how should model look?